# I am trying to use function admin inside the switch case but it displays error. I am using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c

How can I make admin function works inside the switch?

I tried doing it but still got an error using Visual Studio 2017

My program is about creating a pharmacy management system that has 2 access as admin and user. Admin can add or update or delete and the user can search or see expiry date.

Error   C1075   '': no matching token found

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int admin(int1);
int main()
{
    char username[50];
    int password;
    int choice;
    int mainmenu = 1;
    printf(" \n\n\n\t\t\t\t\tWELCOME TO THE PHARMACY MANAGMENT SYSTEM\t\t\t\t\t");

    while (mainmenu == 1) {
        printf("\n\n\n\nPlease choose from the current choices\n \n1.ADMIN \n\n2. "
               "CUSTOMER\n\n3. EXIT\n\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        do {
            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                admin(1);
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                printf(
                    "\n System Closes ...Press Any Key to turn off the system ....");

                mainmenu = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        while (choice = 1);
        {
            printf("\nplease enter your username\t");
            scanf("%s", username);
            printf("\nplease enter your password\t");
            scanf("%d", &password);
            if ((strcmp(username, "admin") == 0) && (password == 123123)) {
                printf("\n\n\t\t\tYou have logged in succefully....\t\t\n");
                break;
            } else {
                printf("\n\t\tThe username or password is incorrect.\n\t\tPlease "
                       "verify that CAPS LOCK is not on,and then retype the current "
                       "username and password.\n\n \a");
            }
            getch();
            return (0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: _"got an error"_ What error did you get?

Comment: Error C1075 '<Unknown>': no matching token found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least following problems (in decreasing importance):

- The final `}` is missing at the very end of the progran
- You havce *declared* the function `int admin(int1)` but you havent implemented the function.
- `int admin(int1)` should be declared `int admin(int)`
- the warning for `getch` is because you forgot to include the `conio.h` header. This header is Microsoft specific.

Consider also platinum95's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues with your loops, I think you expect them to do something different.

```
while (mainmenu == 1)
```

This loops the program until '3' is entered. This seems fine.

```
 do {
     ...
    }

    while (choice = 1);
```

I think you need to look up how do-while loops work. This loop will never exit, as you assign choice to 1 rather than compare it with 1.

```
while (choice = 1);
    {
     ...
    }
```

This is not a loop. That *while(choice = 1)* belongs to the previous do-while loop. You therefore just have a block of code here (which is never executed since the previous loop never exits).

It also seems like the block of code here is intended to be the *admin(int)* function, (which you didn't include, so I presume this is supposed to be it).

Your best option is to go find a tutorial online of how while and do-while loops work, as well as a tutorial on writing and using functions.